# Decoding the entered string or alphabet

Tags: java

I have this program where I am reading data from text file which have data separated by "," in each line. Means left side of comma have alphabet and right side of comma have it's value. I want to enter an alphabet and want my program to give me it's number value which is on right side of comma in the file.
But somehow program is not giving any output, though i tried with else condition also but it is falling in while condition. please someone help me in this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Decoding_message_tom1{

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("I:\\Programming\\Java Tutorials\\sample.txt"));

        // creating Link List 
        LinkedList<Decoding_node_tom1> list1 = new LinkedList<Decoding_node_tom1>();

        // checking if line is not empty         
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
         {
            // splitting the line with delimiter and storing in an array. 
             String data[] = line.split(",");

             // Object creation for passing the values in constructor of Decoding_node_tom1 class.
            Decoding_node_tom1 obj1 = new Decoding_node_tom1(data[0], data[1]);

           // inserting data as data[0] and data[1] in LinkedList object.
             list1.add(obj1);
         }

         // scanner class to scan what user has input
         Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Enter Your encoded message.....");

        // Storing entered Input from user in str1 variable
         String str1 = scn.nextLine();

         // Iterating through list1
         Iterator itr = list1.iterator();


         // This will run until we have next values in iterator.
         while(itr.hasNext())
         {
             Decoding_node_tom1 var = (Decoding_node_tom1)itr.next();

             // Checking if the value entered is equal to values in sample.txt file
             if(var.encode_value == str1)
             {
                 System.out.println("Decode value for " + var.encode_value + " is " + var.decode_value);
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Entered Encode value is Invalid.... ");
                 System.exit(0);
             }
         }

     }
}



public class Decoding_node_tom1 {

    String encode_value;
    String decode_value;

    // Constructor of the above class for assigning the values during the time of object creation.
    Decoding_node_tom1(String encode_value, String decode_value)
    {
        this.encode_value = encode_value;
        this.decode_value = decode_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in the condition:

```
 if(var.encode_value == str1)
```

should be

```
 if(var.encode_value.equals(str1))
```

The reason is that the string instance created when reading stdin is different than the one created when parsing the file: two distinct objects with the same value. the `==` operator compares object *identity*, i.e. checks whether two variables are referencing the same object instance. the `equals()` function checks for object *equality*, i.e. if the "value" of the two objects pointed by the two variables is the same. Note that identity implies equality, but the opposite is not true.

Comment: Thank You, It is working now and thanx for the help :)

Comment: please, accept the answer if it is satisfactory